# Erro ao executar código no netbeans (JAVAFX)

Tags: java, javafx, netbeans

O erro é o seguinte (lembrando que só acontece no javaFX, no swing funciona tudo normal):

> ```
> Exception in Application start method
> java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
> at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:389)
> at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:328)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
> at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:767)
> Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
> at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:917)
> at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$155(LauncherImpl.java:182)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Location is required.
> at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3207)
> at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3175)
> at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3148)
> at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3124)
> at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3104)
> at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3097)
> at teste.Teste.start(Teste.java:22)
> at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$162(LauncherImpl.java:863)
> at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(PlatformImpl.java:326)
> at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
> at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
> at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
> at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
> at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
> at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
> … 1 more
> Exception running application teste.Teste
> C:\Users\Evandro Casanova\Documents\NetBeansProjects\teste\nbproject\build-impl.xml:1052:
> The following error occurred while executing this line:
> C:\Users\Evandro Casanova\Documents\NetBeansProjects\teste\nbproject\build-impl.xml:806:
> Java returned: 1
> ```

Comment: Posta seu código, o erro tá aqui: `Location is required. at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3207)`

Comment: Posta o código da classe principal, que contém o método main e start. O problema está no método start. O caminho do arquivo FXML não deve estar correto.

Answer (score 0):

Evandro, pelo que pude perceber o erro é ao executar o sistema, provavelmente ele nem deve estar abrindo.
**Sugestão:**
 
*1°* Verifique o seu método Start se o caminho do seu FXML está correto.
*2°* Verifique se você não está chamando um método no inicialize.
*3°* Caso esteja chamando um método no botão, verifique se na classe onde encontrasse o método (Geralmente a Controller) se tem a marcação **@FXML** em cima do método. (Erro muito comum esquecer de colocar essa marcação). 
Caso nada disso funcione, veja se consegue detalhar o processo que fez, ou o sistema.

Abraço.